# Yocto package generation without modifying distributions on targets (ARM & x86)

Tags: c++, cmake, cross-compiling, yocto, bitbake

Currently, I'm developing a **C/C++ Application** with the following characteristics:

- **Multiple target platforms** - ARM (Raspbian) and manufacturer-modified x86 distribution
- **CMake** is used to compile C/C++ application
- **Cross-compilation** for ARM and the customized x86 distribution => with CMake (and toolchains to cover cross compilation)
- **Multiple dependencies** (other github repositories) which are separately cross-compiled (according to github READMEs). These are referenced in the CMake of the project. The CMake decides if it uses the ARM or x86 libs.
- For **deploying** I copy the cross-compiled dependency libs to /usr/lib on the target. Afterwards, the cross-compiled application can be launched on the target.

As cross-compilation is very annoying because it's full of pitfalls and I'll need many more dependencies in future, I decided to move to another build system to make things easier:

**My goal is to get a rpm/deb file which can be easily installed on the target systems**

After a few hours of research, I found out that via Yocto cross-compilation can be managed easier. In addition, it's possible to build deb/rpm/... files which can be installed on the targets.

Anyhow, as far as I understood, this deb/rpm/... file can be only installed on the yocto distribution/image which has been used for compiling => In other words, I would have to flash a completely new distribution on our targets (raspberry & x86). Unfortunately, this is no option for me (because of the custom x86 target).

**Question 1:** Is it correct that I have to replace the distributions on the targets in order to install the created packages?

**Question 2:** Is there a way how to create cross-compiled deb files which can be installed on existing distributions? If yes, what do I have to do to achieve this?

I assume that my current build strategy isn't the best. If you have any idea how to make it better, feel free to let me know.

Thanks,
Christoph